# Apache htaccess Rewrite a directory and strip off paramters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Assume I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
Redirect /bla http://www.example.com/blubb/?
```

That works quite well, but i'm redirected this way:

```
http://www.example.com/blubb/?
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid off the question mark after the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^bla/?$ http://www.example.com/blubb/? [L,NC,R=302]
```